# Emojis not rendering in React app, terser plugin build failure

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a react act in which emojis are used in various places. When I run the react app locally in dev mode, everything works fine. However, when I build the react app in production mode, the emojis show up as weird unicode characters.

For instance, the  emoji gets rendered as "ðŸŒ™". There's a relevant post in the create-react-app repo (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488), but I still can't fix the issue. I've tried installing the terser-webpack-plugin and using the "ascii_only" option, but then my build fails.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
            { test: /\.(css)$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] }
        ]
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'production' : 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'app/index.html'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                terserOptions: { output: { ascii_only: true } }
            })
        ],
    }
}
```

**Abbreviate build log (running on AWS CodeBuild)**

```
[Container] 2020/07/31 14:57:35 Running command npm run build
60  
61  > first-component@1.0.0 build /codebuild/output/src878559177/src
62  > NODE_ENV='production' webpack
63  
64  /codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:30
65          } catch {}
66                  ^
67  
68  SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
69      at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
70      at Module._compile (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
71      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
72      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
73      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
74      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
75      at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
76      at require (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
77      at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:26:38)
78      at Module._compile (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
79      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
80      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
81      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
82      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
83      at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
84      at require (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
85      at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js:3:16)
86      at Module._compile (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
87      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
88      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
89      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
90      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
91      at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
92      at require (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
93      at Object.<anonymous> (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/webpack.config.js:2:22)
94      at Module._compile (/codebuild/output/src878559177/src/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
95      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
96      at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
97      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
98      at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
99  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
100 npm ERR! errno 1
101 npm ERR! first-component@1.0.0 build: `NODE_ENV='production' webpack`
102 npm ERR! Exit status 1
103 npm ERR! 
104 npm ERR! Failed at the first-component@1.0.0 build script.
105 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
106 
107 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
108 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-07-31T14_57_36_330Z-debug.log
109 
110 [Container] 2020/07/31 14:57:36 Command did not exit successfully npm run build exit status 1
111 [Container] 2020/07/31 14:57:36 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
```

Comment: syntax error means webpack does not recognize that emoji file. what is the extension?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this solved it - [How can I render emoji in my React app (using Webpack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177398/how-can-i-render-emoji-in-my-react-app-using-webpack).

I also had to downgrade from terser-webpack-plugin 3.x to 2.3.6. Apparently 3.x introduced some breaking Node changes - [how solve error jest-worker at run build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003678/how-solve-error-jest-worker-at-run-build).